# Windows error: "'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized"

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Windows 7 machine, following the instructions shown in [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

The first step there says to run the command

```
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

However, my machine does not recognize the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` command.

```
PS C:\> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The term 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

- **Why does my machine not recognize the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`**
- **How can I proceed to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I proceed to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

The optional Windows feature, `Windows Subsystem for Linux`, cannot be enabled on Windows 7.  What you want is not possible.

- [Windows 10 Installation Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

> Why does my machine not recognize the Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` is a Windows 8+ only command.  The PowerShell cmdlet just uses the DISM module to add/remove Windows Features, in order to do that it requires the version of DISM that comes with Windows 8+, the cmdlet `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` cannot be used on a Windows 7 machine.

> This topic lists the Windows PowerShell modules included with Windows
>   Server 2016 and Windows 10. The Windows PowerShell modules in the list
>   support automating the features of those versions of the Windows
>   operating system and provide links to the cmdlet references for each
>   module. These modules enable you to use Windows PowerShell to
>   administer, maintain, configure, and develop new features for Windows
>   Server 2016 and Windows 10.

- [Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows/get-started?view=win10-ps)

Comment: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` can only be supported if you are running Window Server 2012+ or Windows 8+ the Windows feature `Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` can only be enabled on Windows 10 Version 1607+.