# Enabling Windows Linux Subsystem error

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When running the command `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` in powershell running as admin I get the following error after a short while

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The referenced assembly could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Comment: Try to enable that feature by running `OptionalFeatures.exe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature is not recognized in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1389315/enable-windowsoptionalfeature-is-not-recognized-in-windows-10)

Comment: You were attempting to run a PowerShell command in a Command Prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows error: “'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized”](https://superuser.com/questions/1300748/windows-error-enable-windowsoptionalfeature-is-not-recognized)

Comment: This can't be a duplicate of "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature is not recognized" since the exact error message of this issue is "The referenced assembly could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with freshly installed Windows 10 v. 1803. The only solution that worked for me was upgrading to v. 1809.